# Sprite Animation clearRect alternative?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, sprite-sheet

**WHAT?**  I am attempting to use canvas and JavaScript to display an animation on top of a grid which also must be drawn using JavaScript.  https://jsfiddle.net/cp1wqeeg/6/

**PROBLEM!** To remove the previous frames of the animation I have used clearRect().  This however breaks my grid which I do not want :(

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/cp1wqeeg/5

`ctx.clearRect(50, 100, width, height);`

**QUESTION**  How can I remove the previous frames of my animation without breaking the grid behind my sprite?

Comment: I believe you would have to clear everything then redraw the grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common action here is to clear all and redraw everything.
But it may become cumbersome if e.g in your case, your background doesn't change.

In this case, an simple solution, is to use offscreen canvases, that will act as layers.

First you draw you grid on this off-screen canvas in the init phase.
Then in your loop, you just draw your offscreen canvas on the main context, with the `drawImage` method.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),

fov = 300,
viewDist = 5,
w = canvas.width / 2,
h = canvas.height / 2,
// here we create an offscreen canvas for the grid only
gridCtx = canvas.cloneNode().getContext('2d'),
angle = 0,
i, p1, p2,
grid = 5;

function initGrid(){
/// create vertical lines on the off-screen canvas
for(i = -grid; i <= grid; i++) {
  p1 = rotateX(i, -grid);
  p2 = rotateX(i, grid);
  gridCtx.moveTo(p1[0], p1[1]);
  gridCtx.lineTo(p2[0], p2[1]);
  i++;
}
/// create horizontal lines
for(i = -grid; i <= grid; i++) {
  p1 = rotateX(-grid, i);
  p2 = rotateX(grid, i);
  gridCtx.moveTo(p1[0], p1[1]);
  gridCtx.lineTo(p2[0], p2[1]);
}
gridCtx.stroke();
}

function rotateX(x, y) {
  var rd, ca, sa, ry, rz, f;
  rd = angle * Math.PI / 180;
  ca = Math.cos(rd);
  sa = Math.sin(rd);

  ry = y * ca;
  rz = y * sa;

  f = fov / (viewDist + rz);
  x = x * f + w;
  y = ry * f + h;

  return [x, y];
} 

initGrid();
var width = 200,
height = 200,
frames = 2,
currentFrame = 0,     
 
imageSprite = new Image()
imageSprite.src = 'https://s27.postimg.org/eg1cjz6cz/sprite.png';
  
var drawSprite = function(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(gridCtx.canvas, 0,0); // now draw our grid canvas
  ctx.drawImage(imageSprite, 0, height * currentFrame, width, height, 50, 100, width, height);
  
  if (currentFrame == frames) {
    currentFrame = 0;
  } else {
    currentFrame++;
  }
}
setInterval(drawSprite, 500);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you.  This would do the trick but my actual scene has many more images in it which created an issue with the grid - it was drawn on top of other images.  To resolve this I created a 2nd canvas DOM for the grid and applied z-index values accordingly. https://jsfiddle.net/cp1wqeeg/8/